React-Native Statusbar not responding to style changes
I have a login/register screen with a video in the background for new user to start the app with in this screen i am popping up modals for either the login or register option. When these modals are up I want to change the status bar from transparent and light text to white background and dark text.
To do that I bound them with a state if the modal is shown or not but it only updates like 1 out of 10 modal pops and I have no idea why.
This is my login screen code:
const LoginScreenMobile = ({ onLogin }) => {
    const [loginModalVisible, setLoginModalVisible] = useState(false)

    return (
        <>
            <StatusBar
                style={loginModalVisible ? 'dark' : 'light'}
            />
            <View style={styles.videoContainer}>
                <LoginModal
                    setVisible={setLoginModalVisible}
                    isVisible={loginModalVisible}
                    modalStyle={styles.modalContainer}
                />
                <Video
                    style={styles.video}
                    source={require('../../assets/videos/login-cooking.mp4')}
                    shouldPlay
                    isLooping
                    isMuted
                    resizeMode="cover"
                />
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }} />
                <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Food</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>for</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Family</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <RegisterButton
                        buttonStyle={styles.registerButton}
                        textStyle={styles.registerText}
                    />
                    <LoginButton
                        onLogin={onLogin}
                        buttonStyle={styles.loginButton}
                        textStyle={styles.loginText}
                        setModalVisible={setLoginModalVisible}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        </>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    videoContainer: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
    },
    video: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
        zIndex: -1
    },
    modalContainer: {
        flex: 1
    },
}

and this is my modal pop up:
const LoginModal = ({ isVisible, setVisible, modalStyle }) => {

    return (
        <Modal
            visible={isVisible}
            onRequestClose={() => setLoginModalVisible(false)}
            style={[styles.modalContainer, modalStyle]}
            statusBarTranslucent
        >
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.modalOverlay}>
                <View style={styles.modalView}>
                    {/* Close Button */}
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => setVisible(false)}
                        style={styles.closeButton}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.closeButtonText}>X</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <Text style={styles.modalTitle}>Login</Text>

                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Email"
                        style={styles.input}
                        keyboardType="email-address"
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Passwort"
                        style={styles.input}
                        secureTextEntry
                    />

                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => setVisible(false)}
                        style={styles.loginButton}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </Modal>
    )
}

I have left out some styling, can provide if needed.
I have basically tried it all by now, putting the status bar in other components, updating it with various other variables and ways, getting rid of the video, isolating the status bar and a button to change it, changing to expo and react-native status bars.
No matter what I do, it doesn't seem to generate an update 100% of the time.

Forgot to say: It ALWAYS updates back to white when the modal closes. Which makes me question this even more.

Why not put another status bar component in your modal? Then you can explicitly set the content type per screen

@johnhaup i did that, it doesn't work i don't know why but it gets overwritten by something, i see it turn to black and then back to white sometimes

Update status bar style with barStyle. It's working for me.
<StatusBar barStyle={loginModalVisible ? 'dark-content' : 'light-content'} />

